# Application becomes unresponsive at keyboard input changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7

When I run my application, do some work on it and then change the keyboard input language (via alt+shift or task bar), my C#, .net-4 application became completely unresponsive. meaning mouse click does not effects the window and the window itself cannot be moved. That been said, no hour glass is been displayed and the process does not go into the  "Application do not respond" state, i.e it will not be shutdown by the operation system (windows 7).

I have encountered a problem like this once when I had (in a different application) a deadlock between the UI thread and another thread. I can assure you this is not the case here, I have been debugging this phenomenon from different angles and no thread in the system is at a join whit or sleep state. not only that but the UI main thread is at the UI (normal exsepting messages from the operation system).

to summerise:

- My application is a C# 4 application running on the .net 4 framework.
- The application runs on windows 7 (we have no xp computers to try it on).
- When the input languge changes the application became unresponsive for the user, but windows does not treat it as such and does not make an attempt to force close it.

Did anybody encountered a problem like this before? I could realy use a starting direction on this one...

Comment: No, I cannot reproduce that (changed from German to Russian to Thai and back, and tested).
Did you write some code reacting on a Windows message for the change of the language? And if so, how does it look like?

Comment: I agree, it's hard to give any input with just a vague description of the problem and no code examples... However, it sounds like you have a delegate that is respond to keyboard messages. Is there some event bubbling happening?

Comment: Had a try with an app I'm building and seems to work fine ... Can you maybe strip out unneeded/private/confidential code, and link to a project? I'll be happy to give it a go for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the system does not contain any code that is intended to react to a language change.
I originally thougt that this is the case but is searched to code with no luck, and like i said there is no thread that handles any code that reacts to such.

I would REALY love to bring here a code sample but because I don't know the origien of the problem I cannot put here the "misbehaving code".